# What's the difference between scipy.special.binom and scipy.misc.comb?

Tags: python, scipy

What is the difference between scipy.special.binom and scipy.misc.comb?

In ipython I can see they return different types and also have different accuracy.

```
scipy.special.binom(4,3)
4.0

scipy.misc.comb(4,3)
array(4.000000000000001)
```

However what exactly are they doing differently?

---

Looking at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/generate_ufuncs.py , scipy.special.binom says

```
binom -- binom: dd->d                                      -- orthogonal_eval.pxd
```

scipy.misc.comb calls scipy.special.gammaln whose line in generate_ufuncs.py says

```
gammaln -- lgam: d->d, clngamma_wrap: D->D                 -- cephes.h, specfun_wrappers.h
```

Comment: (I did not downvote) One way of answering these sorts of questions is `inspect.getsource`.

Comment: @Zhenya That's interesting. How do you use it? import scipy.special; inspect.getsource(scipy.special.binom) gives me TypeError: <ufunc 'binom'> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object

Comment: yeah, inspect module fails for C extensions. So you have a partial answer here: `comb` is a pure-python implementation which inspect shows, and `binom` is a ufunc, so you'll need to hunt down `generate_ufunc.py` in the scipy source tree.

Comment: @Zhenya I am not sure scipy.misc.comb is pure python. It seems to just call scipy.special.gammaln

Comment: the `exact=True` code path is python; otherwise, yes, it uses gamma-function. Now that you see it, what is the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whenever you come across a situation where you do not know what some code is doing and it is not straightforwardly easy to simply import the parent module in some interpreter and inspect the execution of the code, the docstrings, etc., then you have a few options.

Let me describe two options that did not turn out to be very helpful this time, but which are a great way to start on a question like this in the future (so that you can include output from these attempts to prove to folks that you tried some stuff before posting here, and to look fancy for knowing what these things are):

You can use the `dis` module to disassemble the Python code into executed op-codes, like so:

```
python -c "import dis; from scipy import misc; print dis.dis('misc.comb(4,3)')"
python -c "import dis; from scipy import special; print dis.dis('special.binom(4,3)')"
```

If using a *nix OS, you can also (almost always) use `strace` to launch something and inspect the system calls that are made. In this case you could look at the output of

```
strace -qc python -c "from scipy import special; special.binom(4,3)"
```

versus

```
strace -qc python -c "from scipy import misc; special.comb(4,3)"
```

(the `-qc` option makes the output less chatty and aggregates the time spent in different system calls, which can be easier to read as a first start. If you omit the `-qc` part, you'll get a big screen dump of all the system calls... something you'll want to open in Emacs and search through, or pipe to a system tool for searching).

In this case, `strace` doesn't help too much and there's a lot of noisy system calls related to just the imports of the modules.

What worked for me this time is `cProfile`:

```
python -c "import cProfile; cProfile.run('from scipy import special; special.binom(4,3)')"
```

In this case, I was able to see that the first execution boils down to a system call into `scipy.special.orthogonal_eval` and Googling this module revealed that we are talking about a shared library, built as the file `orthogonal_eval.so` and I found this [nice page with the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/orthogonal_eval.pxd).

You can see the full function definition of `binom` there, which includes a standard calculation of the factorials involved in the formula for small values, and some approximation with other special functions (I see some calls to "Gamma", "beta" and "lbeta" defined in some file called `cephes.h`).

Looks pretty standard -- if I needed to, I can go dig around that `.h` file and Google some more and probably find a long-standing C library of special functions at the bottom of all of that.

Meanwhile, for `misc.comb` first consider that the [regular documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html) of this is available (whereas, for me, it is not available for `binom`).

The docstring says there is a possible 3rd argument, `exact` which can be set to something other than 0 if you *don't* want a `float` to be returned. In that case, a `long` is returned, but you could cast to `int` if you'd like.

This explains the precision question. You can read in `orthogonal_eval` how if `k` is relatively small, and the answer will give an integer (integer arguments), then something with less round off error is used. Whereas `comb` will only do this if you say `exact=1` (or anything else such that `exact != 0`).

As for the code that `comb` is executing, well, we can [view the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/misc/common.py#L246) that's linked from the SciPy documentation page.

This function is also making use of some helper function calls from `scipy.special` but the mix between what is called in the Python layer vs. the C layer is different, and the implementation for the approximation part is slightly different as well.

I'm not sure what level of specificity you need, but I would say that for most purposes, this level of detail should suffice: `binom` is implemented directly in the C extension layer in `orthogonal_eval` and makes some tweaks to reduce precision issues for small inputs. `misc` implements the small input stuff in Python directly and makes use of `special` calls without passing through `binom` itself -- so there was some amount of reinventing the wheel for whoever programmed these. Since they mix and match function calls between the Python layer and C layer, it's not surprising that there would be some precision differences.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose what I don't understand is why they both exist.

Comment: Other than the unsatisfying "because two different people developed these at two different times," this might be a good opportunity for [dissolving the question](http://lesswrong.com/lw/of/dissolving_the_question/).

Comment: (+1) Great answer. @Anush: a *why* question is a good one. I guess it just so happened a while back that `scipy.special` wraps at least two good ol' specfun libraries, amos and cephes (and a few more things from here and there). If you feel like helping to clean it, help is appreciated: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?labels=scipy.special&page=1&state=open