# Drawing an arc tangent to two lines segments in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, trigonometry

I'm trying to draw an arc of n number of steps between two points so that I can bevel a 2D shape. This image illustrates what I'm looking to create (the blue arc) and how I'm trying to go about it:

1. move by the radius away from the target point (red)
2. get the normals of those lines
3. get the intersections of the normals to find the center of the circle
4. Draw an arc between those points from the circle's center

[image: Beveled Edge]

This is what I have so far:

[image: Matplotlib]

As you can see, the circle is not tangent to the line segments. I think my approach may be flawed thinking that the two points used for the normal lines should be moved by the circle's radius. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong and how I might be able to find this arc of points? Here is my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223685/create-circle-tangent-to-two-lines-with-radius-r-geometry

def travel(dx, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    a = {"x": x2 - x1, "y": y2 - y1}
    mag = np.sqrt(a["x"]*a["x"] + a["y"]*a["y"])
    
    if (mag == 0):
        a["x"] = a["y"] = 0;
    else:
        a["x"] = a["x"]/mag*dx
        a["y"] = a["y"]/mag*dx

    return [x1 + a["x"], y1 + a["y"]]

def plot_line(line,color="go-",label=""):
    plt.plot([p[0] for p in line],
             [p[1] for p in line],color,label=label)

def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][1] - line1[1][1], line2[0][1] - line2[1][1])

    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
       raise Exception('lines do not intersect')

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    return x, y
    
line_segment1 = [[1,1],[4,8]]
line_segment2 = [[4,8],[8,8]]
line = line_segment1 + line_segment2
plot_line(line,'k-')
radius = 2

l1_x1 = line_segment1[0][0]
l1_y1 = line_segment1[0][1]
l1_x2 = line_segment1[1][0]
l1_y2 = line_segment1[1][1]
new_point1 = travel(radius, l1_x2, l1_y2, l1_x1, l1_y1)

l2_x1 = line_segment2[0][0]
l2_y1 = line_segment2[0][1]
l2_x2 = line_segment2[1][0]
l2_y2 = line_segment2[1][1]
new_point2 = travel(radius, l2_x1, l2_y1, l2_x2, l2_y2)

plt.plot(line_segment1[1][0], line_segment1[1][1],'ro',label="Point 1")
plt.plot(new_point2[0], new_point2[1],'go',label="radius from Point 1")
plt.plot(new_point1[0], new_point1[1],'mo',label="radius from Point 1")

# normal 1
dx = l1_x2 - l1_x1
dy = l1_y2 - l1_y1
normal_line1 = [[new_point1[0]+-dy, new_point1[1]+dx],[new_point1[0]+dy, new_point1[1]+-dx]]
plot_line(normal_line1,'m',label="normal 1")

# normal 2
dx2 = l2_x2 - l2_x1
dy2 = l2_y2 - l2_y1
normal_line2 = [[new_point2[0]+-dy2, new_point2[1]+dx2],[new_point2[0]+dy2, new_point2[1]+-dx2]]
plot_line(normal_line2,'g',label="normal 2")

x, y = line_intersection(normal_line1,normal_line2)
plt.plot(x, y,'bo',label="intersection") #'blue'

theta = np.linspace( 0 , 2 * np.pi , 150 )
a = x + radius * np.cos( theta )
b = y + radius * np.sin( theta )
plt.plot(a, b)
plt.legend()
plt.axis('square')
plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I intuitively think that this only works for targets that equidistant from points. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco Hi! Thanks for the message. If I understand you correctly, the two points needed for the arc are the same distance away (the radius value of 2) from the red point, aren't they?

Comment: Yea exactly. I rise this issue because it is not explicitly specified in your question. I just wanted to be sure that you knew this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making a Bezier curve, like in this [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/quad_bezier.html). A basic implementation might be:

```py
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Path = mpath.Path

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# roughly equivalent of your purple, red and green points 
points = [(3, 6.146), (4, 8), (6, 8.25)]

pp1 = mpatches.PathPatch(
    Path(points, [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE3, Path.CURVE3]),
    fc="none",
    transform=ax.transData
)

ax.add_patch(pp1)

# lines between points
ax.plot([points[0][0], points[1][0]], [points[0][1], points[1][1]], 'b')
ax.plot([points[1][0], points[2][0]], [points[1][1], points[2][1]], 'b')

# plot points
for point in points:
    ax.plot(point[0], point[1], 'o')

ax.set_aspect("equal")

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

To do this without using a Matplotlib `PathPatch` object, you can calculate the Bezier points as, for example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644499/1862861), which I'll use below to do the same as above (note to avoid using scipy's `comb` function, as in that answer, I've used the `comb` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531361/calculating-the-number-of-k-combinations-with-and-without-scipy)):

```py
import numpy as np
from math import factorial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def comb(n, k):
    """
    N choose k
    """
    return factorial(n) / factorial(k) / factorial(n - k)


def bernstein_poly(i, n, t):
    """
     The Bernstein polynomial of n, i as a function of t
    """

    return comb(n, i) * ( t**(n-i) ) * (1 - t)**i


def bezier_curve(points, n=1000):
    """
       Given a set of control points, return the
       bezier curve defined by the control points.

       points should be a list of lists, or list of tuples
       such as [ [1,1], 
                 [2,3], 
                 [4,5], ..[Xn, Yn] ]
        n is the number of points at which to return the curve, defaults to 1000

        See http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/
    """

    nPoints = len(points)
    xPoints = np.array([p[0] for p in points])
    yPoints = np.array([p[1] for p in points])

    t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n)

    polynomial_array = np.array(
        [bernstein_poly(i, nPoints-1, t) for i in range(0, nPoints)]
    )

    xvals = np.dot(xPoints, polynomial_array)
    yvals = np.dot(yPoints, polynomial_array)

    return xvals, yvals


# set control points (as in the first example)
points = [(3, 6.146), (4, 8), (6, 8.25)]

# get the Bezier curve points at 100 points
xvals, yvals = bezier_curve(points, n=100)

# make the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# lines between control points
ax.plot([points[0][0], points[1][0]], [points[0][1], points[1][1]], 'b')
ax.plot([points[1][0], points[2][0]], [points[1][1], points[2][1]], 'b')

# plot control points
for point in points:
    ax.plot(point[0], point[1], 'o')

# plot the Bezier curve
ax.plot(xvals, yvals, "k--")

ax.set_aspect("equal")

fig.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you so very much for your reply. Though I'm using it to demonstrate my project, my actual project to bevel a point is not in Matplotlib. Do you know of a way to get these points with Python or Numpy, perhaps?

Comment: I've updated to answer to include how to get the Bezier curve points without using Matplotlib. This was essentially based on  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644499/1862861

Comment: Matt, thank you very much. This works really well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not just interested in the solution but in better understanding of this problem, you should read the article on `Curved Paths` that Amit Patel wrote in his 'Red Blob Games' blog.

https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/curved-paths/

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223685/create-circle-tangent-to-two-lines-with-radius-r-geometry

def travel(dx, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    a = {"x": x2 - x1, "y": y2 - y1}
    mag = np.sqrt(a["x"]*a["x"] + a["y"]*a["y"])

    if (mag == 0):
        a["x"] = a["y"] = 0;
    else:
        a["x"] = a["x"]/mag*dx
        a["y"] = a["y"]/mag*dx

    return [x1 + a["x"], y1 + a["y"]]


def calculate_angle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    # calcuate the two vector
    # vector 1: point1 to point 2
    vec1 = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)  
    # vector 1: point1 to point 3
    vec2 = (x3 - x1, y3 - y1)
    # calculate dot product
    dot_product = vec1[0] * vec2[0] + vec1[1] * vec2[1]
    # calculate magnitude
    magnitude_vec1 = math.sqrt(vec1[0]**2 + vec1[1]**2)
    magnitude_vec2 = math.sqrt(vec2[0]**2 + vec2[1]**2)
    # calculate the angle for two vector
    angle_rad = math.acos(dot_product / (magnitude_vec1 * magnitude_vec2))
    # rad to degree
    angle_deg = math.degrees(angle_rad)
    return angle_rad

# output unit: 45.0 (degree)

def plot_line(line,color="go-",label=""):
    plt.plot([p[0] for p in line],
         [p[1] for p in line],color,label=label)

def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][1] - line1[1][1], line2[0][1] - line2[1][1])

    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
       raise Exception('lines do not intersect')

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    return x, y


line_segment1 = [[1,1],[4,8]]  # endpoint p1,p2 for line1 
line_segment2 = [[4,8],[8,8]]  #endpoint p2,p3 for line2
line = line_segment1 + line_segment2
plot_line(line,'k-')
radius = 2  #the required radius
# angle
angle = calculate_angle(4, 8, 1, 1, 8, 8)  #red point,purple point,green point
#print(angle)

#the distance between point1 and radius from point1
dist=radius/np.tan(angle/2)

l1_x1 = line_segment1[0][0]
l1_y1 = line_segment1[0][1]
l1_x2 = line_segment1[1][0]
l1_y2 = line_segment1[1][1]
new_point1 = travel(dist, l1_x2, l1_y2, l1_x1, l1_y1)

l2_x1 = line_segment2[0][0]
l2_y1 = line_segment2[0][1]
l2_x2 = line_segment2[1][0]
l2_y2 = line_segment2[1][1]
new_point2 = travel(dist, l2_x1, l2_y1, l2_x2, l2_y2)

plt.plot(line_segment1[1][0], line_segment1[1][1],'ro',label="Point 1")
plt.plot(new_point2[0], new_point2[1],'go',label="radius from Point 1")
plt.plot(new_point1[0], new_point1[1],'mo',label="radius from Point 1")

# normal 1
dx = l1_x2 - l1_x1
dy = l1_y2 - l1_y1
normal_line1 = [[new_point1[0]+-dy, new_point1[1]+dx],[new_point1[0]+dy, new_point1[1]+-dx]]
plot_line(normal_line1,'m',label="normal 1")

# normal 2
dx2 = l2_x2 - l2_x1
dy2 = l2_y2 - l2_y1
normal_line2 = [[new_point2[0]+-dy2, new_point2[1]+dx2],[new_point2[0]+dy2, new_point2[1]+-dx2]]
plot_line(normal_line2,'g',label="normal 2")

#plot circle
#find the center of circle
x,y=line_intersection(normal_line1,normal_line2)
theta = np.linspace( 0 , 2 * np.pi , 150 )
a = x + radius * np.cos( theta )
b = y + radius * np.sin( theta )
plt.plot(a, b)
plt.legend()
plt.axis('square')
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j32xh.png)

Comment: Please, clarify what the code does, and how and why it answers the question. Visit the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for more details.